# Using CASE WHEN to check if a UserID exists within a column

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I created a temp table that creates a list of userid's of users that are subscribed to two different lists. So the table looks something like this:

```
|userid|
+++++++++
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want to create a Yes/No flag simply is any value for userid is present in this row. I tried building it out like this:

```
CREATE TABLE temp.flags AS
SELECT distinct userid,
                         CASE WHEN _______
                         then 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Both
FROM temp.usertable
```

I want the output to look this:

```
|userid|
+++++++++
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd reverse the logic:

```
SELECT distinct 
  userid,
  CASE WHEN userid IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END as is_userid_present
FROM temp.usertable
```

But you could also:

```
SELECT distinct 
  userid,
  CASE WHEN userid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as is_userid_present
FROM temp.usertable
```